# Determine the entropy of an ideal bosonic gas

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, statistics, bose-einstein-condensate

I am struggling with this problem.

So we're told that any macroscopic state of a gas can be characterized by microscopic stated of a single particle. We divide the microscopic states into groups. So $j$ is the number of groups, $G_j$ is the number of states in the $j$ group and $N_j$ is the number of particles in that $j$ group.

We are asked to find the formula of entropy of an ideal bosonic gas, which is at equilibrium and found in an arbitrary macroscopic state, in terms of $n_j$ which is the average number of particles in a state of a group, aka $n_j=N_j/G_j$.

I have tried to start from the equation
$$\mathrm{d}S=-k\cdot\sum(p\cdot\ln(p))$$
And I assumed the probability $p$ would mean the probability in the Bose-Einstein distribution, but it didn't really take me anywhere and I'm very confused.